# Linq Lambda groupby and projection problem

Tags: linq, lambda

If I have some data like:
Model   ModelName Code
Aris    1.2       1
Aris    1.3       2
Corolla 1.1       3
Corolla 1.4       4

I would like to create a groupby query with a new projection something like:

```
var vehicles = _vehicleRepository.GroupBy(x=>new {x.Model,x.ModelName,x.Code})
                    .Select(g => new { Text = g.Key.Model + " - " + g.Key.ModelName, g.Key.Code })
                    .ToList();
```

It seems I am having difficulty with the Text = g.Key.Model + " - " + g.Key.ModelName and it causes SQL errors

Any tips appreciated

Comment: *What* SQL errors does this cause?

Comment: Does it cause SQL errors, or does it cause exceptions on the client side about not being able to translate to SQL or something else related but not about an error executing the query? There is a huge difference.

Comment: SQL Errors. Problem seems to be with the SQL generated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest fix for this may simply be to perform the concatenation at the client instead:

```
var vehicles = _vehicleRepository.GroupBy(x => new {x.Model,x.ModelName,x.Code})
                .Select(g => g.Key)
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(k => new { Text = k.Model + " - " + k.ModelName, 
                                   k.Code })
                .ToList();
```

Here the `AsEnumerable` effectively makes the rest of the query just run at the call site, in .NET. I've included an extra projection to *just* get the key from each group, so that no more data is transferred than necessary.

Another option might be to use `Distinct`:

```
var vehicles = _vehicleRepository.Select(x => new {x.Model,x.ModelName,x.Code})
                .Distinct()
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(k => new { Text = k.Model + " - " + k.ModelName, 
                                   k.Code })
                .ToList();
```

It's possible that you don't need the call to `AsEnumerable` here - you could certainly try removing it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jon, but could not get them to run.

Comment: As I know your AsEnumerable() fetches all data, Is this true? If is, it's better to run a stored procedure for this not using linq.